# How do I attach JSON Stringify to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable :

```
var testData;
```

And I have a function that populates an array. Goes through an array and makes another array like so :

```
var person = {
    "Name": obj.Name,
    "Age": obj.Age,

}
partsObject.push(person);
```

I then want to make this array into JSON so I can use it with my D3 objects, so I do this :

```
testData = JSON.stringify(partsObject);
```

I can console log this variable, but when trying to go through it via D3's forEach method like so :

```
   testData.forEach(function(d) // data is the JSON
        {
```

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: testData.forEach is not a function`

I don't understand how I can log the variable to the console yet it's as if I can't use it as JSON. Any ideas ?

Comment: Does a string have a `forEach()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name suggests `stringify()` converts a JavaScript object (the JSO in JSON) into **a string** of JSON. You can `console.log()` it because `console.log` expects to take a string, and anything that's not a string is converted to one to be displayed.

If you want to use it as an array again, you need to parse your string of JSON back to the JavaScript object: `JSON.parse(testData)`.

Answer (score 2):

You really dont need to stringify your Array to pass to d3. Do not to get confused with javascript objects, since `forEach` requires an array to loop through and you are passing a string to manipulate with `forEach` function

use:

```
partsObject.forEach(function(d) 
 {
   ...
```

`JSON.stringify(partsObject);` creates a string as`"{'Name':'ABC','Age':23}"`

`Uncaught TypeError: testData.forEach is not a function` caused because javascript was not able to find an Array

Answer (score 1):

You are currently trying to loop through a String since you **stringify** your array.

Just do `partsObject.forEach` and don't stringify your Array.

Comment: That last sentence is incorrect. A JavaScript object is a JavaScript object, not "a JSON". JSON is a notation, which is simply a way of representing something as text.

Answer (score 1):

`.stringify()` turns a Javascript Object into a string. You would want to either run

```
partsObjects.forEach()
```

or alternativily you could turn the stringify'ed string back into an object with

```
(JSON.parse(testData)).forEach()
```